# Automapper mapping between complex structures

Tags: automapper

I am AutoMapper in my asp.net core project.
I need to map ProjectStructure to Job.
Here are my classes.Any help will be appreciated.
I could not figure out from documenation

---

```
public class ProjectStructure
{
    public CustomerInfo CustomerInformation { get; set; }
    public int JobInformationID { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerInfo
{
    public DateTime PreferredMeasureTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public ContactDetail ContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDetail
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UnitNo { get; set; }
    public string StreetNo { get; set; }
}

public class job
{
    public int jobID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<address> addresses { get; set; }

}


public partial class address
{

    public long id { get; set; }

    public string unitNumber { get; set; }

    public string streetNumber { get; set; }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a AutomapperConfiguration class as such:

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize((config) =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<ProjectStructure, Job>()
                  .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
                            {
                                dest.JobID = src.JobInformationID;
                                dest.Addresses = new List<Address>
                                {
                                    new Address
                                    {
                                        StreetNumber = src.CustomerInformation.ContactDetails.StreetNo,
                                        UnitNumber = src.CustomerInformation.ContactDetails.UnitNo
                                    }
                                };
                            });
        });
    }
}
```

And then call `AutoMapperConfiguration.Initialize();` method in your startup class (whatever that is)

Answer (score 0):

I have another map defined using like this

```
    CreateMap<ContactDetail, address>()
            .ForMember(m => m.city, opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.SuburbAddress))
            .ForMember(m => m.streetNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.StreetNo))
            .ForMember(m => m.street, opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.StreetAddress))
            .ForMember(m => m.town, opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.SuburbAddress))
            .ForMember(m => m.unitNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.UnitNo))
            .AfterMap((ContactDetail, address) => { address.contactType = "Site"; address.tvStart = DateTime.Today; });
```

How i can use this in .AfterMap instead of mapping each property?